# Is this good to avoid injection requests

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have to get IP and URL in request parameter and I need to avoid injection specially from url string, here is my code:

```
if(filterValidIp($ip) && filterValidUrl($url)) {
    //it's ok 
    //code....
}
```

function for url:

```
function filterValidUrl($s) {
    $s = trim($s);
    $valid = filter_var($s, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
    if(!$valid === false) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

url:

```
?url=http://google.com?id=ss'+&ip=127.0.0.1
```

pass as valid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code you have presented *validates* the URL.

If you're planning to store it in a DBMS you should also escape it using [`mysqli::real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [`PDO::quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

You may also want to sanitize it, especially if you'll present it to unsuspecting visitors to your web site. You can do that using [`filter_var($s, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).

Remember that untrusted people can enter malicious text strings into web sites.